# How do I set a Number Input Into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the value input by the user to var numberr, Not the value that is already there eg(value="9").

I might be completely doing the wrong thing I just want to know how to store a value Inputted by the user :/

```js
var numberr = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;


function myFunctionVar() {
  document.getElementById("myNumber").value = numberr;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="9">
  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Where is the user inputting a number? How are you calling `myFunctionVar()`?

Comment: When does your function get called? If it's called before the user has entered their value then it will see the old value. Maybe you want to set up an event listener to the 'change' event so that your function is called only when the input value changes.

Comment: Shortly found a good solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433557/how-to-save-user-input-into-a-variable-in-html-and-js/54037203

Comment: just call the function `myFunctionVar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `parseInt`

```js
document.getElementById("btnmyNumber").addEventListener("click", myFunctionVar);
function myFunctionVar() {
  var numberr = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value, 10);
  alert(numberr);
```

```html
<form >
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="9">
<input type="submit" id="btnmyNumber">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
  let myNumber;
  let input = document.querySelector('#myNumber')
  input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    myNumber = e.target.value
    console.log(myNumber)
  })
```

Vote up if it helped)

Comment: `myNumber = Number(e.target.value)`