# Pass a javascript variable to another page when form is submitted. with just html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good day, I am trying to pass a java script variable along with 2 user inputs. I am unable to get the code to work the email and name go to HighScore.php just fine, but I keep getting zero for the hidden field. highscore1 is the name of the variable.  I don't know J Query, so I need a HTML java-script solution.  Thank you for looking.

```
 <form method="post" name="form" action="HighScore.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="username">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
            <input type="hidden" name="highscore1" id="hidden_score" value= highscore1>
            <input type="submit" name="add" value=Enter>

        </form>
```

Comment: Hidden variable must have quotes for value... It's first that i found here...

Comment: Question: `highscore1` is a `php` variable?

Comment: highscore1 is a java-script variable the page sending the information is in html and java-script.

Comment: If it's a js variable we need to see where it is initialized

Comment: @Jason you want to pass 2 input text fields & one hidden JS field to HighScore.php

Comment: Yes Kumar exactly that but the hidden field is a JS variable

Comment: MYkola I  added this right above the form and it still sends zero  <script> let highscore1 = 10; </script>

Comment: @Jason you can get by <?php  

echo $_GET['hidden_score'];

?>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save user input into a variable in html and js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433557/how-to-save-user-input-into-a-variable-in-html-and-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case, you should first use javascript to get/set hidden_score input, you can use it anywhere in your html page, as long as you ensure that input is fully rendered, you can simply add it inside of `$(function() { /*you can put your code here*/ })` for jQuery version, and `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { /*you can put your code here*/ })`for javascript  version

```
<script>
document.getElementById("hidden_score").value = "Set value here";
</script>
```

And then, in your HighScore.php, you can use this for getting that value depend on form method: $_POST['hidden_score'] for post and $_GET['hidden_score'] for get

Comment: That was a simple and elegant solution it worked perfectly. Thank you and everyone else that took the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setHighScore()
{
    document.getElementById("hidden_score").value = "Set value here";

}
```

now you can call the above function on any event that meets your requirement

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but inside the form I can not call a function or can I?  I just want to add the javascript value to what gets posted to the HighScore.php page.

Comment: yes you can do it inside the form also yo can do it this way: .<input type="hidden" name="highscore1" id="hidden_score" value= "document.getElementById("hidden_score").value = "Set value here";">

Comment: You can just put the function in your `<script>` tags, and remember to wrap any code that affects DOM elements with: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){   ...   });`